# TextJoin like function based on a condition in on SQL

Tags: sql, function, google-bigquery, pivot, transpose

Trying to figure out if it is possible to do a textjoin like function in SQL based on a condition. Right now the only way I can think of doing it is by running a pivot to make the rows of the column and aggregating them that way. I think this is the only way to transpose the data in SQL?

**Input** This would be a aql table (tbl_fruit) that exists as the image depicts

SELECT *
FROM tbl_fruit

[image]

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: MySQL, Oracle, Postgres...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL (without specifically listing each column, thus in a way that it scales ...)

```
#standardSQL
select `Group`, string_agg(split(kv, ':')[offset(0)], ', ') output
from `project.dataset.table` t,
unnest(split(translate(to_json_string((select as struct t.* except(`Group`))), '{}"', ''))) kv
where split(kv, ':')[offset(1)] != '0'
group by `Group`
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - output is

[image]

Comment: I know this is "better" than GMB's solution because it scales but it should be noted for a small number of columns (say less than 10) I would expect this solution to be much slower

Comment: should scale well to a reasonable number of columns (btw, otherwise this would be good indication that something really wrong with design of such a table). you can try/experiment by yourself and share result with community :o)

Comment: I'm not saying it would be to slow -- probably fine -- but you are calling about 9 functions -- and functions called by row are the 2nd most comment reason people post about sql not performing well on this site.

Comment: i don't think this is a problem with BigQuery - obviously unless overused - which is not this case. At the end of the day - you need to achieve desired result so you do your best to make it and above solution is good for more generic cases when number of columns are big enough and column names are not known in advance! when there are very few columns and names are known - you can use simpler approaches

Comment: Yes that was the point I was trying to make -- this is good for the big cases and GMB's is good for the few column cases.

Comment: no. no any changes needed rather than just try to use `safe_offset(1)` instead of `offset(1)`. Note; the error you showed above  - means that your real data somehow different from example you provided in your question

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant would you be able to explain the solution a little bit more? what does kv represent and output at the end of the first line? Currently trying to adapt this for another use case where instead of having all fruits together in one cell, each value your have its own row and the group would be repeating

Answer (score 1):

In Big Query, you could do this with arrays:

```
select grp,
    array_to_string(
        [
            case when apples  = 1 then 'apples' end,
            case when oranges = 1 then 'oranges' end,
            case when bananas = 1 then 'bananas' end,
            case when grapes  = 1 then 'grapes' end
        ],
        ','
    ) as output
from mytable
```

This puts all the columns in an array, transcoding each `1` to the corresponding literal string and `0`s to `null` values. Then `array_to_string()` builds the output CSV string - this functions ignores `null` values by default.

Answer (score 0):

As a beginner I tried in my own way.

```
with pt as (select Group_,
 concat( case when Apples  = 1 then 'Apples,' end,
         case when Oranges = 1 then 'Oranges,' end,
         case when Bananas = 1 then 'Bananas,' end,
         case when Grapes  = 1 then 'Grapes,' end)
opt from fruit)
select Group_,stuff(opt,len(opt),1,'') output from pt
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hA701sSz)