# GBQ Unpviot Columns into single column and multiple rows

Tags: google-bigquery, transpose, unpivot, unnest

Hi All Trying to figure out a similar solution to a  [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65345650/textjoin-like-function-based-on-a-condition-in-on-sql) but slightly different solution. I am trying to figure out a way to unpivot a varying number of columns and have the results be in one column

**Input** This would be a sql table (tbl_fruit) that exists as the image depicts

SELECT * FROM tbl_fruit

[image]

**Output**

[image]

**Potential Solution**
Per the linked question I am trying to rework that solution but keep having errors

```
select `Group`, split(kv, ':')[offset(0)] output
from tbl_fruit t,
unnest((select as struct t.* except(`Group`))) kv
where kv[offset(1)] != '0'
group by `Group`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select `Group`, split(kv, ':')[offset(0)] output
from `project.dataset.table` t,
unnest(split(translate(to_json_string((select as struct t.* except(`Group`))), '{}"', ''))) kv
where split(kv, ':')[offset(1)] != '0'
```

with output

[image]